# Inserting Child Objects in Firebase

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to insert child category objects in categories parent object. For some reason it only inserts the last category object.

```
  func saveFlowerCategories() {

        let annuals = FlowerCategory(id: 1, title: "Annuals",subtitle :"Plants that just last one season. These plants will die in the winter. ", imageURL: "annuals.jpg")

        let perennials = FlowerCategory(id: 2, title: "Perennials",subtitle :"Plants come back year after year. These are also very less expensive", imageURL: "Perennial.jpg")

        let rootRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
        let categoriesRef = rootRef.child("categories")

        let categories = [annuals,perennials]

        for flowerCategory in categories {

            let categoryRef = categoriesRef.child("category")
            categoryRef.setValue(flowerCategory.toDictionary())
        }
    }
```

Comment: you want to append to your  JSON?

Answer (score 0):

**This block here:**

```
    for flowerCategory in categories {
        let categoryRef = categoriesRef.child("category")
        categoryRef.setValue(flowerCategory.toDictionary())
    }
```

`categoryRef` is always going to equal `categoriesRef.child("category")`. This means that in the following line, you set the value to your `flowerCategory.toDictionary()` on every iteration of this for loop.

Basically what you are doing is overwriting the value of the same key over and over until the loop finishes, leaving you with only the final value stored.